# How can I find and break connections to my Linux via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, root

I have root rights on my Linux. I logged in from outside but forgot to disconnect. How can I find and break connections to my Linux via ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# netstat -atpn | grep ssh
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.X:22         192.168.1.Y:43381     ESTABLISHED 1772/sshd
```

In my case, the `1772` is the PID of the process of the SSH shell. You need to find out which one is it (probably deducting from the source IP address, which in my example is `192.168.1.Y`).

Once you got it clear, simply kill it:

```
# kill -9 1772
```

You **should** change your root password if you left it unattended for a while, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Using w you can see the current users on the system include their user name and where they come from (IP address in terms of SSH). You can then use the IP address to filter with netstat:

```
[root@server ~] # w
 23:25:40 up 6 days, 16:41,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
joakim   pts/0    22.231.113.64    Mon22    2days  0.00s  0.00s -bash
[root@server ~] # netstat -natp | grep 22.231.113.64
tcp        0      0 194.66.82.11:22             22.231.113.64:57235          ESTABLISHED 8435/sshd
[root@server ~] # kill -9 8435
```